# ReactJS react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router

I'm developing am application with ReactJS, but I have a problem.

That's my Router

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route name="Home" path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}></IndexRoute>
        <Route name="Stores" path='stores' component={Stores}>
        <Route name="List" path='/stores/list' component={StoreList}></Route>
        <Route name="Create" path='/stores/create' component={StoreCreate}>   </Route>
    </Route>
    <Route name="404: No Match for route" path="*" component={NoMatch} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

The route to Stores 
Don't exists. But, when I click in the link to this route, they must redirect do "StoreList"

```
<Route name="Stores" path='stores' component={Stores}>
```

So I did:

```
    class Stores extends React.Component {

      componentWillMount() {
        this.setUrlParameters();
      }

      setUrlParameters() {
        if (!this.props.children) {
          this.context.router.push({
              pathname: '/stores/list',
              query: {
                  page: 1,
                  limit: 10
              }
          });
        }
      }

      render() {
        return (this.props.children);
      }
    }
```

The first time that I click in the link, they do perfect the redirect.
But if I click again, they not call **componentWillMount** and the redirect doesn't exec.

Can someone help me?

Comment: try calling this.setURlParameters() in componentDidUpdate instead of componentWillMount

Comment: Thank you!! That's works perfect!!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try calling this.setURlParameters() in componentDidUpdate instead of componentWillMount